# android button layout smarty two rows if not enough space

Tags: android, layout

I have 5 buttons. I would like to put it into a row or two rows. I would like them to be center_horizontal. I tried below code:

```
 <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button android:id="@+id/btn_abc"  
        android:text="Speak"  
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />  
<Button android:id="@+id/btn_abc"  
        android:text="Speak"  
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />  
<Button android:id="@+id/btn_abc2"  
        android:text="Speak"  
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />  
     .....x3                         
  </LinearLayout>
```

I expect the above code can handle for different screen size. Use 1 row if enough space. Use 2 rows if not enough space.
However, in a real 4" phone device, when there is not sufficient width, it still use 1 row only, why? thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: not so relevant url. I know i can use multiple xml but I want to use one xml only. Please study and modify my XML code. I expect it will give me my expected effect, but it does not. What is wrong? or please let me know if this is not possible. (I wasted so much time to try this idea and is still trying), thanks!

Comment: Making android:layout_width="0dp" and android:layout_weight="1" for each Button view, will make them use full screen width and display in one row.

Comment: A `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation will only layout one row regardless of space. What you seem to want is a "`FlowLayout`", which is not present in Android, but you can find the code for implementing it if you search for it. Or you could define a custom layout for portrait in a different manner.

Comment: thanks, i found the prefect solution! https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Download and import the 'android-flowlayout' project.
Right click the project 'android-flowlayout' and select "android" -> click 'Is library'

In your app, right click the project and select "android" -> import library, add 'android-flowlayout' project.

Then simply replace the xml linearlayour with:

```
<org.apmem.tools.layouts.FlowLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
>
```

P.S. but it seems it can not be center horizontal. But still, a nice solution!

Answer (score 3):

Google now have provide **Flex Layout**   https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

1) add to your project

> dependencies {
>       compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.3' }

2) Use in layout

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:flexWrap="wrap"
    app:alignItems="stretch"
    app:alignContent="stretch" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_flexBasisPercent="50%"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_alignSelf="center"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview3"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_alignSelf="flex_end"
        />
</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

3) Play around with this 2 parameters

- **flexDirection** direction children items are placed inside
- **flexWrap** wrap flex container in single-line or multi-line

[image]

Comment: Great solution! Lib's size is less than one Kb and it's fully customizable. Must have lib!